# Getting user input in tkinter failing

Tags: python, tkinter, get

I'm creating a GUI to download files from websites using tkinter.
but i'm getting an unexpected error
The code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import urllib.request

root = Tk(className='VideoDownloader')
root.geometry("400x200")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

Lab = ttk.Label(root, text='Download a file from any site')
Lab.grid(row=0, column=0)


def down():
    u = url.get()
    n = name.get()
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(u, n)

Lab1 = ttk.Label(root, text='Enter file name :')
Lab1.grid(row=1, column=0)

name = ttk.Entry(root,)
name.grid(row=2, column=0)

Lab2 = ttk.Label(root, text='Enter video url :')
Lab2.grid(row=3, column=0)

url = Text(root,)
url.grid(row=4, column=0)

but = ttk.Button(root, text='Download', command=down())
but.grid(row=5, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Creates the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    but = ttk.Button(root, text='Download', command=down())
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test.py", line 14, in down
    u = url.get()
TypeError: get() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

In my last project i created a GUI to compare numbers and get() do not require a argument

Comment: `url` is not an `Entry`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Url` is a `Text` widget, not an `Entry` widget. If you just want one line, use an `Entry` widget, and the `get()` method will work fine.

---

For a `Text` widget, which can have multiple lines, use the following to get all input:

```
url.get("1.0",END)
```

"1.0" means that the input should be read from the first character of the first line. END is a tkinter constant which is set to the string "end", and means to read until the end of the widget. Infact this will add a newline character to the end of the input, so you should use a customized string:

```
'end-1c'
```

meaning one character before the end.